# how to delete only certain strings and characters but not japanese using str.replace and regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I have some annotated grammar data in a total dataframe that look like the following:

```
{おもしろい|ADJ}{本|N}を読んだ
このまえ{あたらしい|ADJ}{雑誌|N}を{いくつか|QUANT}買った
```

about 1,000 of these.

I'm trying to strip the `{}, |,` and words Roman letters that come between the `|` and `}`
(I don't want to strip all Roman letters, since have data that has like `SF` and I want to preserve that

```
{SF|GEN}の{本|N}を読んだ
```

The code that I am trying to implement is:

```
df['text_data'].str.replace(r'\{(.+?\|[A-Za-z_]+)\}', "\1").astype(str)
```

and the desired output is:

```
おもしろい本を読んだ
このまえあたらしい雑誌をいくつか買った
SFの本を読んだ
```

This works in Atom if I do a search and replace, but the results that I am currently getting are the Japanese characters that are outside the curly brackets:

```
を読んだ
このまえを買った
のを読んだ
```

I'm also looking to see if I can also at the same time apply spaces between the }{ (I have some def and apply space rules that I can use, but if I can do it while the search/replace is happening, that would be even better)

```
おもしろい 本 を読んだ
このまえ あたらしい 雑誌 を いくつか 買った
```

Comment: I think you want `r"\1"`. Notice the `r`.

Comment: @MarkRansom cool! so that half resolved it - it replaced all curly brackets but i still have the roman letters after, e.g, おもしろい|ADJ

Comment: Unless your data is all like the one you showed, it might be a better idea to parse this into an intermediate representation first rather than trying to mess around with regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

s = """{おもしろい|ADJ}{本|N}を読んだ
このまえ{あたらしい|ADJ}{雑誌|N}を{いくつか|QUANT}買った
{SF|GEN}の{本|N}を読んだ"""

r = (r"\{([^|]+)" +  # {left
     r"\|" +         # |
     r"[A-Z]+\}")    # right}

print(re.sub(r, r"\1", s))
```

Outputs:

```
おもしろい本を読んだ
このまえあたらしい雑誌をいくつか買った
SFの本を読んだ
```

---

To add spacing between the `"}{"`, simply run this on `s` **before** running the regex:

```
s = s.replace("}{", "} {")
```

Outputs:

```
おもしろい 本を読んだ
このまえあたらしい 雑誌をいくつか買った
SFの本を読んだ
```

Comment: thanks! i tried running it in my data frame and i got an error `expected string or bytes-like object` when i tried `df['text_data'] = re.sub(r, r"\1", df1['text_data']` <- i would like to be able to run it within my dataframe, rather than assigning the column like `s = df['text_data']`

Comment: You can use the pandas API for regex like you were doing before. I'm just showing an example with pure python.